# problem with for loop in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to execute the following loop inside my script in order to send mail to all users in a certain file that I write in earlier in the script. I check if the file $eUsers is not empty I execute the following:

```
for name in `cat $eUsers | cut -d' ' -f2`
do
echo "message" > /letter
cat /letter | mail -s "message" $name
done
```

- At the beginning of the script I define $eUsers= "/filename".
- The code : `cat $eUsers | cut -d' ' -f2` gets back the user name. I tried it out in the terminal, and it's working. I tried putting the above code in a separate file and replaced "$eUsers" with its path (/filename), and it worked without any problems.

However, when I use that code in my script, after writing in the file $eUsers, it goes into an infinite loop. I dont' understand why it's doing so. In the original file, the infinite loop seems to occur because of the line `cat /letter | mail -s "message" $name`.

Comment: try running your script with -x option `#!/bin/bash -x` at the top so you can view a verbose output.

Comment: There's nothing in the script as posted that should cause an infinite loop. I'm assuming that `/letter` (and `/filename`) represents a longer path since it would be unusual to put a file directly in the root directory. I'm also assuming that there's some reason that you output the message to a file, since `echo "message" | mail ...` would work without needing a file. If you try the `-x` as suggested it may show you where the problem is or if you can post more details we may be better able to help. I think it's probably some other part of the code that is actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read junk name; do
  echo "message" | mail -s "message" "$name"
done < "$eUsers"
```